# Testing RJDBC connections with time limit

Tags: r, time, evaluation

How can I test if a `RJDBC` connection is working? With time limit?

Here is a toy code:

```
library("RJDBC")

testConnection <- function(){
  tryCatch({
    conn <- RJDBC::dbConnect(JDBC("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "driverPath"), "connString", "user", "password")
    dbDisconnect(conn)
    return("Connection: OK")
  }
  , error = function(e)  {
    return("Connection: Failed")
  }
  )
}

testConnection()
```

But if there is no network connection, I have to wait for 30 seconds to have the result.

I need to test many connections, so I would like to change the test limit to 2 seconds.
How can I set a evaluation time limit?

I tried `setTimeLimit` without success.